# WinRT c# - Text Block scroll auto to the end

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, scroll, textblock

I would like to scroll auto to the end of a textblock if I add text to it. But I try a lot of thing, but I failed hard.

Anybody has a good idea to do this on a WinRT application ?

Thanks for your time, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Step 1** - Get WinRT XAML Toolkit from NuGet
- **Step 2** - Add following `using` to your code

  ```
  using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions;
  ```
- **Step 3** - Make following call after you add (replace really) the `Text` in the `TextBox`

  ```
  var scrollViewer = textBlock.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
  ```